# Why is there so much more hair in render than viewport?

Tags: particles, hair

Ok Ive checked relevant settings and made sure under "display" in my hair particle settings, it is 100%. I dont know why, in latest 2.8, there is so much more hair in render vs viewport - for example the hair looks normal in viewport, then in (cycles) render I get -

[image]

Here are other settings:

[image]

Is it to do with hair dynamics? even with that off, I still get this increase in hair.

Comment: Check that Subsurf levels for viewport and render are equal. Also check other modifiers - they must have same setup for render and viewport

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the children *display* and *render* amount, there is another **Amount** option under the **Viewport Display** panel. You might have set it low. So at render time its rendering 100% of the hair particles.

[image: Viewport Display panel]